# Windows Terminal launches extra window with error - cannot find file

Tags: windows, terminal

I have a 404 style error when launching Windows Terminal.

[image: Windows Terminal Launch Errors]

As you can see, the path has been split in to **2** parameters on the space in `"Program Files"`.

Does any one know how to correct this please?

Research:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73324061/error-when-opening-windows-terminal-to-ubuntu?rq=2

I did consider the above, but its not relevant. We are talking the cmd application with a launch variable being passed to it, which has changed somehow. I can open the bash profile tab as normal tho' with no errors.

Profile I use:

[image]

Start-up command i use:

[image]

Comment: Change the Settings to fit what you want. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-is-now-the-default-in-windows-11/   .  Also try to reset to Default.    ....  I did this to get back to the regular command window.

Comment: Which profile are you using, and how is startup command written?

Comment: I updated my question to provide my context, @harrymc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going out on a limb, but do you have "Open windows from a previous session" enabled?

I'm guessing that you at some point ran a command like the one that's displaying the error there (which looks like it escaped the args incorrectly). Then you closed the window, and the Terminal *remembered* that tab, and the commandline that was used to run it. Now, when you reopen the Terminal, it'll re-start by attempting to reopen that tab.

You can probably double-check that hypothesis by looking at the `state.json` file that's [next to the `settings.json` file](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQ)#where-can-i-find-the-settings-file) for your terminal install.

Comment: Oh my days - you are right, there is an entry in the state.json file like you say. Can i manually remove it or should i turn off the setting from with in the GUI ?

Comment: You can absolutely delete those entries. Any that you delete from the list, the Terminal will try to re-autodetect, and then re-add the GUIDs it finds bach to the `state.json` after it creates those profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Run Windows Terminal and enter Settings
- Select the Ubuntu profile on the left
- Click on "Command line" on the right
- Change `ubuntu.exe` to `wsl.exe`
- Click Save
- Exit Terminal.

For more information with screenshots see :
[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1486711/963426).

Comment: I will give it a go and let you know ... mine seems to related to the git bash exe.

Comment: Yes, this advice will probably not work for the git bash. Can you install it in a folder with no blanks in the path?

Comment: It has been working this way for ages mate, but i see your point. I can try moving to another location to see if the issue goes away - meanwhile i have elastic search headaches to deal with first, thanks for replying.